# aspx/c# Refresh on closing popup

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a little problem with my code.

I have an `asp:Wizard` element, in which I have few steps.
In one step, I click on a button that open a popup with `window.open` to select a datetime.
When I selected one, the popup is closing, but the datetime is not visible in my parent window (but it's there, because when I click again on my `window.open` it's "reloading" my page and the date is now visible)
I already tried to reload my parent's page when I close the popup with `window.parent.opener.location.reload` but this solution make me lose the active step of my wizard.
So what I need is a partial refresh of my page that keeps the current step.
below is the code

My opener:

```
var childWindow = window.open("../../Utils/CalendarPopup.aspx?DatePred=Stateme‌​‌​ntDateFrom", "", "height=280; width=285;);
 childWindow.onunload = function () 
{ // Where i need to reload }
```

My popup:

```
Session[Request.Params["DatePred"]] = CalendarSelectDate.SelectedDate;
Session["CalendarPopupCanceled"] = 0;
this.ClosePage();
```

The data loading:

```
if (Session["StatementDateFrom"] != null)
        {                
            {
                (WizardProcess.FindControl("DtTxtBxStatementDateFrom") as Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Shared.DateTimeTextBox).IsNullDate = false;
                (WizardProcess.FindControl("DtTxtBxStatementDateFrom") as Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Shared.DateTimeTextBox).Value = System.Convert.ToDateTime(Session["StatementDateFrom"]);
            }            
            Session["StatementDateFrom"] = null;
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: share your code

Comment: Opening:
var childWindow = window.open("../../Utils/CalendarPopup.aspx?DatePred=Stateme‌​ntDateFrom", "", "height=280; width=285;); childWindow.onunload = function () { 
// Where i need to reload
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know how you wrote your code, but why you need to reload the child window. If you have a control (for example a textbox) that displays the datetime you selected from the childWindow, then you can set the control's value equal to the selected datetime. This should be easier than trying to refresh only the wizard!

Comment: Yeah It's another person who code this, and I have to code in it now, so I don't know exactely how it works.
I just see that the value is changed in a c# function and this function was only called on the onload method. So I need to call this one at the 'onunload' of my popup and it should work, i think?

Comment: ok, as i said, you can try setting the value using JS onunload function. Here: childWindow.onunload = function () { // Where i need to reload };

Comment: Yes but I already have a C# function that do this with full controls on it, it
 is easier to just call this one no?

Comment: the c# function controls code behind, you cannot refresh a window in frontend using c# function. what i meant is to keep everything as it is, but only when closing the child windows, do something like  this: var date = $('#datetimepickerid').val(); $('#textboxdatetime').val(date);

Comment: Oh yes i forgot about the problem of refreshing in code behind. Thanks, i'll try this !

Comment: if it works, don't forget to mark it as answer please :) thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help =)